# sum within a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a hard time to finalize a task and I need your help. 
I have a table(mytable) that consists of something like:

```
ID;price;cost; +70 more columns
```

What I need is to find for each ID what would be the

```
cost*(price/(sum(price) "group by ID"))
```

Cost is one and the same per item.

I reached this table after 4 pages of coding and it is alive within the query, which means that I cannot call it again(at least I do not want to)

Any ideas how I can do this in a smart way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `WITH GroupPrice AS (SELECT ID, SUM(Price) SumPrice FROM MyPrice GROUP BY ID) SELECT t.ID, t.Cost * (t.Price / g.SumPrice) FROM MyTable t JOIN GroupPrice g ON t.ID = g.ID` — give or take syntax errors and or wrong order for parts of WITH clause, etc.  You could also write the CTE (WITH clause) as a query in the FROM clause of the main query instead.

Comment: Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you could be using:

```
select  id,
        cost * ratio_to_report(price) over (partition by id)
from    table
```

Comment: I always forget about ratio_to_report

Answer (score 1):

This cost*(price/(sum(price) "group by ID")) is actually pretty close to what I would have done using `SUM() OVER`

```
 select 
     id,
     cost*(price/(sum(price) over (partition by id)))
From
      table
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c3135/10)

Comment: So, would it that work out :select 
     mytable.*,
     cost*(price/(sum(price) over (partition by id)
From
      mytable

Comment: If you're asking if you can add `table*` to the select clause, then [yes you can](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c3135/13). However I don't recommend it since it can lead to problems down the road. Just do a `select Column_name || ',' from all_tab_cols where table_name = 'table_name'` and copy/paste the results into whatever client you're working in.